# API for monitoring client -> server collection update status in Meteor

Tags: meteor, ddp

Most collaborative online tools for editing documents, such as Google Docs, provide a message verifying that your changes have been saved after edits are made.

I'd like to do the same in Meteor; provide the user a message indicating whether given changes recently made on the client have or have not propagated successfully to the server. I'd expect some simple way to ask "Have all client-side changes been accepted by the server?"

I couldn't find one - is there a supported API to do this? I can poke around the Meteor.Collection._* properties but would rather not use internal, apt-to-change platform methods and variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that collection operations are really just methods, under the hood. So they provide the option to specify a callback function as well (see http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert). So if you want to be certain that your operations, such as an `insert`, succeeded, then just provide such a callback and use it to update whatever indication you want to provide to your users.
For instance:

```js
Documents.update(currentId, {$set: {text: "my new text"}}, function(err, count) {
     if (err) {
        Session.set('status', "Error saving document!");
        alert("Couldn't save changes.");
     } else {
        Session.set('status', "All changes saved.");
     }
});
```

Comment: Some further info for anyone else - understand that, if you call any Meteor.Collection method from a Meteor method AND define the callback within that Meteor method, the callback will be executed individually on both the client and the server - in other words, the client may indicate success even if the server hasn't written the data yet.  In order to receive a callback on the client based on server state, the callback must be defined only on the client. Only then will the callback wait to return until the server has signified success. I suppose this makes sense but was not intuitive.